# OpenApi or Json:Api Generics support?

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, code-generation, json-api

I have a C# API that returns a Payload<T> object for pretty much every request. I want the OpenApi spec that is generated (by any package available) to enable generics support so that the output is JsonPayload<Foo> instead of a ton of classes with the names FooJsonPayload. Also, ideally there is typescript support for the client.

I'm currently using swagger to generate OpenApi3.0 spec. I'm open to using different spec generators, and any client generator as well to get the desired result. I could really use some help and hope on this.

```
C#
    public class JsonPayload<T>
    {
        public virtual bool IsSuccess => !this.Errors.Any();
        public virtual List<string> Errors { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public virtual T? Data;
    }
```

> Just spent the last 6 hours trying to find an answer for this and still haven't found it. WHY though? This should be an extremely common use case. And it isn't just this time, either. I've literally run into my past self looking for the same solution from three separate years. Why are generics not a thing yet? Very frustrating.